# compact embedding of $H_0^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ into $L_2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I was just wondering how to think about this problem. Is it that $H_0^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ is compactly embedded into $L_2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ I know how it would be for the real case using the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem, but I cannot figure out how the complexity necessarily changes things. The proof in Evans is only for real functions.

Best wishes,

Catherine

Comment: $\Bbb{C}$ doesn't change anything over $\Bbb{R}$, that's why nobody discuss it specifically.

Comment: Can you go into more details?